# I use an old editor which writes information to the VirtualStore but still reads from Program Files (x86)

Tags: virtualstore

I use an old editor which originally was designed to save its state on exit into a few files in its installation directory under c:\Program Files (x86)...

Clearly it can't do that now, so Windows 10 redirects those files to be written in the relevant VirtualStore location.  However when I restart the editor it reads that information from the c:\Program Files (x86)... area.

How do I get it to look in the VirtualStore location?  The editor won't have an option for that as VirtualStore never existed when it was released.

Comment: I got around it by updating the shortcut to the program to Run As Administrator.  Not ideal but works.

Comment: that's now stopped working for some reason